# Android issue with clickable TextView

Tags: android

I have a fragment and LinearLayout with two TextViews. When I click at LinearLayout I want to do something. But my app breaks down.

This is my Java class:

```
public class MyClass extends Fragment implements LocationListener {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public NejblizsiBary() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy,
                container, false);

        return rootView;
    }

    public void detaily(View v){


    }
```

This is my XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity$DummySectionFragment" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/section_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffdf33"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:onClick="detaily"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nazev"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:text="Restaurace u Androida"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/adresa"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:text="Imaginární 12"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Include the full stack trace and point out the line causing the crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it will give crash if you are using `android:onClick` attribute and defining the method in the fragment class.

The ultimate reason is because `android:onClick` is implemented by looking for the method on the view's Context, which will (usually) be your Activity. Views have no concept of fragments, so there is no way for them to find a method on a fragment or know what fragment they should even be looking at.

**Solution:**

There are 2 possible solutions:

1. Define a click listener and set it into the LinearLayout.
2. Define a method in the Activity from where you are replacing fragment.

Comment: I hove no reputation :-( But it very help to me.